# phpStorm - Highlight the line number when there is a error?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

In phpstorm IDE is there a way to set the settings of the IDE to

```
1. Show the whole coding line in red when there is a error, including the line number on the left ?

2. Like in Dreamweaver to when pressed shit+enter it to insert a <br /> ?
```

is these things are possible to do in this phpstorm IDE 7.1 ?

Comment: 1) Whole line: No. It can only highlight actual error place + scrollbar marker. This is enough -- already easy to spot. 2) You can record a macro where you are typing such text .. and then assign whatever shortcut you want in `Settings | Keymap`

Comment: most of the times i tend to overlook the tiny highlights in the corner of the line like ";". if this error was highligeted in the line it would have been much easy for the debugging and for the developer attention...

Comment: Well.. I also sometimes get confused about error place because in default color scheme it is just a red underwave. That's why I've also added red-ish background -- looks more visible. But once again: it's not about "which line has an error" -- my case is about "which place/column exactly". **Anyway:** if you wan to make sure that you see all errors/warnings detected by IDE in this file, just use `Code | Inspect Code...` -- you will see a list of all issues in separate window. The slight problem is that you need to run/refresh it manually (and it does not follow current file automatically).

Comment: @LazyOne It sometimes not enough, I switched from netbeans to phpstorm and in most cases it seems to be better, but in this case, it not supporting whole line background styling, only the contained text error, now when I realize F2 will take me to the error, I can live with that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes this is possible. Simple press 'f2' or 'shift+f2'

For more information visit: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html

Comment: PHPStorm version 11.0.6 working well, save time for me. Thank you so much